# The r2 that I evaluate is wrong, it is negative and too high

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, anaconda, spyder

Good morning I'm using a neural network in order to predict a physical quantietis. After predicting it, I want to understand if there is a correlation with another feature, so I plot the graph attached below where I can see that there is a big correlation. Then I want to evaluate the r2, but there is an error because the result is - 10.187, that is impossibile. Moreover if I evaluate the r2 with excel it is correct because r2 = 0.86, as you can see below.

Who can I fix it?

These are the plot, the first with python and the second with excel (with the r2).

[image]

[image]

This is the code:

```
# =============================================================================
# Carico le librerie
# =============================================================================
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras import optimizers
from keras import regularizers
from keras import backend
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from keras.regularizers import l2


# =============================================================================
# Scelgo il test size
# =============================================================================

test_size = 0.20


# =============================================================================
# Carico il dataset e scelgo label e features
# =============================================================================
dataset = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv', decimal=',', delimiter = ";")

label = dataset['Label']
features = dataset.drop(columns = ['Label'])

# =============================================================================
# Per la normalizzazione
# =============================================================================
y_max_pre_normalize = max(label)
y_min_pre_normalize = min(label)

def denormalize(y):
    final_value = y*(y_max_pre_normalize-y_min_pre_normalize)+y_min_pre_normalize
    return final_value

# =============================================================================
# Suddivido il dataset in train e test
# =============================================================================

X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(features, label, test_size = test_size, shuffle = True)

# =============================================================================
# Estraggo le feature che mi serviranno nella seconda rete, perchè così sono 
# già state mischiate da shuffle 
# =============================================================================

feat = ['18','19','20']
features_post_train = X_train1[feat]
features_post_test = X_test1[feat]

X_train1 = X_train1.drop(columns = ['18','19','20'])
X_test1 = X_test1.drop(columns = ['18','19','20'])


y_test2 = y_test1.to_frame()
y_train2 = y_train1.to_frame()

# =============================================================================
# Normalizzo
# =============================================================================
scaler1 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler2 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler1.fit_transform(X_train1)
X_test = scaler2.fit_transform(X_test1)


scaler3 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler4 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
y_train = scaler3.fit_transform(y_train2)
y_test = scaler4.fit_transform(y_test2)





# =============================================================================
# Mi serve per avere come metrica R2
# =============================================================================
from keras import backend as K
def r2_score(y_true, y_pred):
    SS_res =  K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred)) 
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square(y_true - K.mean(y_true))) 
    return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot + K.epsilon()) )

from datetime import datetime
logdir = "logs/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir) 

# =============================================================================
# Creo la 1° rete neurale
# =============================================================================
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model = Sequential()
c= 1e-10
# ,kernel_regularizer=l2(c), bias_regularizer=l2(c)
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],), activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation = 'linear',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))

model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ['mse', r2_score])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 200,
                    validation_split = 0.1, shuffle=False, batch_size=250
                    )

history_dict = history.history

loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values = history_dict['val_loss']
r2_score_train = history_dict['r2_score']
r2_score_val = history_dict['val_r2_score']

y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)

y_train_pred = denormalize(y_train_pred)
y_test_pred = denormalize(y_test_pred)



# =============================================================================
# Plot di y reali vs previste 
# =============================================================================
plt.figure()
plt.plot((y_test1),(y_test_pred),'.', color='darkviolet', alpha=1, marker='o', markersize = 2, markeredgecolor = 'black', markeredgewidth = 0.1)
plt.plot((np.array((-0.1,7))),(np.array((-0.1,7))),'-', color='magenta')
plt.xlabel('True')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')
plt.title('Test')
# plt.set_title('R2: ' + str(r2_score(y_test_pred, y_test1)))

# plt.savefig('figure11.png', dpi=150, bbox_inches="tight")

plt.figure()
plt.plot((y_train1),(y_train_pred),'.', color='darkviolet', alpha=1, marker='o', markersize = 2, markeredgecolor = 'black', markeredgewidth = 0.1)
plt.plot((np.array((-0.1,7))),(np.array((-0.1,7))),'-', color='magenta')
plt.xlabel('True')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')
# plt.set_title('R2: ' + str(r2_score(y_train_pred, y_train1)))
plt.title('Train')
# plt.savefig('figure21.png', dpi=150, bbox_inches="tight")

# =============================================================================
# Plot di R2
# =============================================================================
plt.figure()
plt.plot(r2_score_train,'b',label = 'r2_score_train')
plt.plot(r2_score_val,'r',label = 'r2_score_val')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('r2_score')
plt.legend()

# =============================================================================
# Plot della loss
# =============================================================================

plt.figure()
plt.plot(loss_values,'b',label = 'training loss')
plt.plot(val_loss_values,'r',label = 'val training loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss Function')
plt.legend()
# plt.savefig('figure31.png', dpi=150, bbox_inches="tight")

# =============================================================================
# Valuto R2, mse e RMSE
# =============================================================================
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

print("\n\nThe R2 score on the test set is:\t{:0.3f}".format(r2_score(y_test_pred, y_test1)))

print("The R2 score on the train set is:\t{:0.3f}".format(r2_score(y_train_pred, y_train1)))
from sklearn import metrics


score = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test_pred,y_test1)
print("\n\nFinal score test (MSE): %0.4f" %(score))
score1 = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train_pred,y_train1)
print("Final score train (MSE): %0.4f" %(score1))
score2 = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test_pred,y_test1))
print(f"Final score test (RMSE): %0.4f" %(score2))
score3 = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train_pred,y_train1))
print(f"Final score train (RMSE): %0.4f" %(score3))


# =============================================================================
# Unisco le variabili estratte prima con quella predetta dalla rete (MSS_EO_Pred)
# =============================================================================

label_old = y_train2.append(y_test2)
label_old = label_old.to_numpy()
label_old = pd.DataFrame(label_old)


new_feat = features_post_train.append(features_post_test)

dataset = X_train1.append(X_test1)

dataset = pd.concat([dataset,new_feat],axis = 1)
dataset2 = dataset
dataset = dataset.to_numpy()
dataset = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
y_test_pred = pd.DataFrame(y_test_pred)
y_train_pred = pd.DataFrame(y_train_pred)

label_predicted = y_train_pred.append(y_test_pred)
label_predicted = label_predicted.to_numpy()
label_predicted = pd.DataFrame(label_predicted)
label_predicted.columns = ['MSS_EO_Predicted']
dataset = pd.concat([dataset,label_predicted],axis = 1)
dataset = pd.concat([dataset,label_old],axis = 1)

print("The R2 score on the train set is:\t{:0.3f}".format(r2_score(dataset.iloc[:,-5],dataset.iloc[:,-2])))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(dataset.iloc[:,-2],dataset.iloc[:,-5],'b.')
plt.xlabel('EO Pred')
plt.ylabel('TP Misurato')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Your code computes the coefficient of determination, not the correlation coefficient, so there is no actual issue other than interpretation of the results.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro yes, I know, but the one evaluated by excel is also the coefficient of determination (R2), so I don't understand why evaluating it in python with r2_score returns me inconsistent number. The datas are the same, as you can see in the plots.